# No translation for MenuItemLink's primaryText in react-admin

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest, react-admin

I'm using a custom user menu and the primarytext is not translated as expected.
No problems with the others components.

```
const MyUserMenu = props => 
    <UserMenu {...props}>
        <MenuItemLink
            to="/configuration"
            primaryText="labels.configuration"
            leftIcon={<SettingsIcon />}
        />
    </UserMenu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to explicitly translate it as the `MenuItemLink` component is not currently responsible for translations (might be a good feature request btw).

```
import { translate, UserMenu, MenuItemLink, translate } from 'react-admin';

const MyUserMenu = translate(({ translate, ...props }) => 
    <UserMenu {...props}>
        <MenuItemLink
            to="/configuration"
            primaryText={translate("labels.configuration")}
            leftIcon={<SettingsIcon />}
        />
    </UserMenu>
```

Comment: translate inside translate!

Comment: translateception

Answer (score 0):

it should be wrapped with curly brackets

```
"{labels.configuration}"
```